# Checking if the files were downloaded correctly with rclone

Tags: rclone

I'm looking for a way to check if the files were downloaded correctly by using rclone. Maybe the option `-i` is able to do that?

```
rclone sync -i SOURCE remote:DESTINATION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option --checksum is able to do that.
https://rclone.org/docs/#c-checksum

When rclone has finished copying a file, it compares checksums. Add option -vv to see hashes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I still don't see how do you know the files were transferred completely? I am using a python script, that in the middle use a command line with rclone synce, and upload local files to google drive. I don't get any output from the run, even when using --checksum. How can I tell it worked?